# How to Address DOM-based XSS from Security Review

Tags: security-review, dom, xss

I have a remoting function on my page that takes a list of contacts, and displays them in on Lightning Design styled page. It works fine, but the final **innerHTML** statement gets flagged in security review as being a DOM based XSS vulnerability. I can't easily use the JSEncode functions, since I using JS Remoting, so trying to work out what I need to do to make this secure in the eyes of the Security Review team?

***EDIT***
Based on this [post](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/DOM_based_XSS_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet), sounds like I'd need a client side encoder?

```
function getEmailTargetList () {

  Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
                '{!$RemoteAction.KWAC_CampaignTargetsExtension.getEmailTargets2}',
                sName,
                sAccountName,

            function(result, event){
                if (event.status) {
                  var outputDiv = document.getElementById("contactList"); 

                  var html = '<div class="slds-scrollable--x"><table id="targetemailcontacts" class="slds-table slds-table--bordered">';    

                  html += '<thead><tr><th scope="col">Action</th>';
                  html += '<th scope="col">Account name</th>';
                  html += '<th scope="col">Contact ID</th></tr></thead><tbody>';    
                  j$.each( result, function(index, value) {
                      html += '<tr><td><button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral slds-m-top--small selectRow" type="button">Select</button></td>';
                      html += '<td>' + value.Account.Name + '</td>';
                      html += '<td>' + value.Id + '</td></tr>';
                  });
                  html = html + '</tbody></table></div>';
                  outputDiv.innerHTML = html;

                }
              },
                {escape: false}
            );
}
```

Comment: Is your JS code inside static resource ?

Comment: Possibly related to [Alternatives for innerHTML in jQuery](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/106340/alternatives-for-innerhtml-in-jquery).

Comment: Re static resources,  no it isn't since that breaks merge fields which I am using in some other places.

Comment: I'd read the problem as being the usage of `value.Account.Name`. If I was going to attempt a XSS attack on that page I'd try and make an Account name that injects HTML characters. Because it isn't escaped when the HTML is built I could probably get a bold tag or similar injected. From there "All Your Salesforce Are Belong to Us!"

Comment: If your HTML is injected in static resource I don't think security team will have any problems .If you have merge fields still you can carry them to static fields via JS global variables .

Comment: @AdrianLarson This post makes me think those alternatives are not enough (and escape has now been deprecated in JS): http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/96273/salesforce-security-review-error-possible-xss-escape-false/96429#96429

Comment: @MohithShrivastava No way using global variables is more secure...

Comment: @Adrian Larson You mean JavaScript global variables are unsafe ..This means none of my apps would have passed security  reviews .Once data is rendered on browser there is no way you can prevent it to be accessed by any Javascript variables .

Comment: @MohithShrivastava You can at least make it harder with [Self-Executing Anonymous Functions](http://markdalgleish.com/2011/03/self-executing-anonymous-functions/). I am surprised usage of global variables isn't flagged as a concern, tbh.

Comment: My inclination is to just add this library and be done with it... https://github.com/SalesforceEng/secure-filters

Comment: @AdrianLarson Ah Self Executing Anonymous function is good alternative .@BritishBoyinDC I still feel if you just move your HTML injection inside static resource it wont be questioned at all from sec review team .

Comment: @MohithShrivastava Doesn't that seem like a gap in the review process itself? If this is a vulnerability, then moving its location does not make it more secure.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Moving to static resource I typically do a uglify and minify .May be this seems like a gap or scanners dont detect when script does it inside static resource or probably static resources make it more secure for attacker to do an XSS